# Перемещение 2D объекта в Godot Engine

Tags: разработка-игр, godot

Сегодня начал учить Godot. Пишу прогу, простейшую... Которая двигала бы мячи по сцене.

```
extends KinematicBody2D

var speedX = rand_range(-3, 3)

func _ready():

    pass

func _process(delta):
    position.x += speedX
```

Запускаю - ничего не происходит. Что делать?

Comment: Не двигается т.к. изменение позиции для KinematicBody2D через position неверно

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так

```
extends KinematicBody2D
var vel = Vector2() #это создаём вектор хранящий в себе значения x и y
var speedX #это переменная

func _ready():
    randomize() #делаем по настоящему случайное число
    speedX = rand_range(-3, 3) #генерируем его
func _physics_process(delta):
    vel.x = speedX #задаём вектору со значением x скорость
    vel = move_and_slide(vel, Vector2(0, -1)) #используем функцию которая используется для перемещения объекта KinematicBody2D
```

Если необходимо перемещение по оси `y`, то задавай значения переменной `vel.y`

Answer (score 0):

Нет такого свойства `position`, есть `rect_position`.

Answer (score 0):

В ready попробуй убрать pass и вообще здесь он не нужен. А еще попробуй сделать в место position отдельную переменную в виде Vector (2 или 3 в зависимости от 2D или 3D) и что бы это значение изменялось переменная += speedX. И в конце сделай move_and_slide(Переменная)

```
extends KinematicBody2D

var speedX = rand_range(-3, 3)
var velocity = Vector2(0, 0)


func _physics_process(delta):
    velocity.x += speedX
    move_and_slide(velocity)
```

Answer (score 0):

проблемы две:

1. твою переменную speedX нужно сначала закинуть в рандомайзер, а потом вернуть уже значение, что делается вот так:

```
var speedX

func _process(delta):
    speedX.randomize()
    speedX.randf_range(-value, value) #randf — для float, randi — для int
```

2. узел kinematic body должен перемещаться через методы и только. move_and_slide(), move_and_collide(), move_and_slide_with_snap(). но если ты подразумеваешь движение мячиков не игроком, а просто силами гравитации и столкновений, лучше пользуйся rigid body, который для этого и предназначен.

Answer (score 0):

Добавь  `velocity = move_and_slide()` в конце.

Думаю это поможет.